# SVN load new dir

Tags: svn, load

So I have setup SVN on my centos (/var/svn/repos/*) - I have a dump which I want to load onto the following URI file:///var/svn/repos/myproject1 - How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `svnadmin load` and, potentially, `svnsumpfilter`. The process and commands are well described in [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create directory for repo `cd /var/svn/repos/`+`mkdir myproject1`
2. Create new empty repo `svnadmin create myproject1`
3. Load data from dump `svnadmin create myproject1 < dumpfile`

Check Manual:  SVNBook